# How to get the reason for the connection failure from the NEVPNManager IKEv2?

Tags: ios, vpn, networkextension, nevpnmanager

I'm trying to establish an IKEv2 connection on iOS using the NEVPNManager.

I update my profile successfully using NEVPNProtocolIKEv2 and start the connection process but after a few seconds the connection stops without any error.

Is there any way I can get more information about the connection to see why it failed? There does not appear to be anything helpful in the NEVPNManager object.

How to track the error in the screenshot? Where is the call back from this PopUp?
Thx!

[image]